# how to write web service for User registration in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

```
@GET
    @Path("/GetFeeds")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String feed()
    {
        String feeds  = null;
        try 
        {
            ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
            ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
            feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
            //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
        //  System.out.println(gson.toJson(feedData));
            feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return feeds;
    }
```

This method i have for getting data from database in Json format.

now i have one User Table in database   in that Firstname and phone number now i want write web service method so that i can store user first name and phone number i am new in web service please suggest me method so that i can write web service how i will implment i am writing web service in java .

Answer (score 0):

There was various frameworks that helps you write this with easy. Apache wink is the one which I have used most frequently. 
In order to write , i assume you will make @POST call , so you will have a method annotated with @POST which will accept request (It can be jax generated objects too).

Visit the apache wink doucmentation for more details .It's easy to get started with.

Post here if you encounter any issues.

Comment: i have written http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html this rest web service for fetch data from datbase now i want to insert user table using web service please help me

Comment: please suggest i am really new in web service . i understand fetch web service now i want insert data in web service

Comment: can i have email id ...i have user table i have to create onwebservice(URi) so that i can insert value in database from that URI

Answer (score 0):

You are using REST service . CRUD database operations can be mapped to POST, GET , UPDATE , DELETE methods of REST.
Once you specify @Path , @Method , framework will accordingly call the specified method when it receives a request for a particular URL.
Within the business logic of the method, you can call your service classes which interacts with the database (DAO).

Comment: I have to insert 2 value u just give method how i will write method so that i can insert database http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html following this post